# Mongodb find a value inside the array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, sails.js

If I have this schema...

```
person = {
emails : Array
}
```

The values are stored in emails array as mentioned below:

```
emails : [{ a : "a@a.com" , b: "b@b.com" , c : "c@c.com" }]
```

Now i tried the below mentioned queries ,

```
 Person.findOne({emails : "a@a.com"}).exec(function(err,person){

 });
```

### Mongodb native query

```
Person.native(function(err,collection){

collection.find( emails : { "$in" : "a@a.com"} , function(err , result){
    //code
 });
```

### });

### EDITED QUESTION

Now i tried using OR as below.

```
Person.findOne({ 
"or": [ 
    {"emails.a": "a@a.com" },
    {"emails.b": "a@a.com" },
    {"emails.c": "a@a.com" }
]
}, function(err,doc) { });
```

Actually , i have to check "emails.a" have "a@a.com" , if not only , i have to find whether "emails.b" or "emails.c" have "a@a.com".

if "emails.a" have "a@a.com" , then the doc should return the output.
else search for "a@a.com" continues in "emails.b" or "emails.c".

How can i do that?

But I didn't get the required output using the above query. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you comment on why you're storing your emails in an array with a single value which is an object with keys "a", "b", "c", instead of a simple array?  If you had just `emails: ["a@a.com", "b@b.com", "c@c.com"]`, then what you're trying would work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array contains a sub-document with keys `a`, `b` and `c`. In order to match the value you want you need to specify this element.

```js
Person.findOne({ "emails.a": "a@a.com" }, function(err,doc) {
```

If you are expecting to do this across the different fields you combine this with [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```js
Person.findOne({ 
    "$or": [ 
        {"emails.a": "a@a.com" },
        {"emails.b": "a@a.com" },
        {"emails.c": "a@a.com" }
    ]
}, function(err,doc) {
```

Please note that this is matching the "document" and not just the member of the array.

Also see the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator for it's uses.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. In case,                                                                  emails : [{ a : "a@a.com" , b: "b@b.com" , c : "c@c.com" }]. In this a , b and c won't be there always. if i use $or , it throws an mongoerror : $or requires nonempty array

Comment: @Mahahari are you sure you are doing it exactly the same as shown. The query works for me.

Comment: Person.findOne({ 
    "or": [ 
        {"emails.a": "a@a.com" },
        {"emails.b": "a@a.com" },
        {"emails.c": "a@a.com" }
    ]
}, function(err,doc) { });      This worked out . Thanks a lot.